# How to retrieve details of a contact from phone and save it in app using flutter

Tags: flutter

I am developing an app in flutter. I save the customer details(name,phone number,email,address,company name) in the app. when I click on button "Add contact from phone" I want to save a contact from phone contacts i.e retrieve contact details from phone contacts and save in customer details.(No need to type;it will autofill).
I have a search button. On clicking the search button phone contacts are displayed. I want to click on that contact and save its details in my app.
Can anyone please help me. I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

By you can do by [contactsService](https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service) . This is an example :

```
  Future getPhonContacts() async {
    List<ContactDetailModel> models = [];
    List<Contact> contacts =
        (await ContactsService.getContacts(withThumbnails: false)).toList();
    print(contacts[0].phones);
    contacts.map((item) {
      var mobiles = item.phones.where((element) => element.label == 'mobile');
      if (mobiles != null && mobiles.length > 0) {
        var number = mobiles
            .map((e) => ContactDetailModel(
                title: item.displayName,
                value: e.value,
                type: ContactType.PHONE.type))
            .toList();
        models.addAll(number);
      }
    }).toList();
```

In my example you just get list of mobiles of user contacts.

Answer (score 0):

Use this package to work with contacts https://pub.dev/packages/contacts_service

```
// Add a contact  
// The contact must have a firstName / lastName to be successfully added  
await ContactsService.addContact(newContact);  
  
// Delete a contact
// The contact must have a valid identifier
await ContactsService.deleteContact(contact);  

// Update a contact
// The contact must have a valid identifier
await ContactsService.updateContact(contact);
```